# Incremental or online learning for multi-class classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have used OneVsRestClassifier of sklearn for multi-class classification. I need improve my model by adding incremental learning. I am not able to find any incremental learning that supports multi-class.

Comment: Doesn't options in [documentation of sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) suit you? They all support multi-class classification (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: ```OneVsRestClassifier``` is not actually the real classifier which uses another classifier underneath and learns multiple of them. And there are many options of classifiers which support incremental learning in sklearn. Can use any one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn OnevsRestClassifer has partial_fit method for the model can use it to incrementally fit the model.

[partial_fit in onevsrest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.partial_fit)

```
clf.partial_fit(x1, y1)
# get x2, y2
# update accuracy if needed
clf.partial_fit(x2, y2)
```

Comment: Thank you. this is what i was looking for